# Custom tree style in HTML/JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create [this structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsAXK.png) in HTML/CSS and Javascript but I'm having trouble with the lines. 
[image]
Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="okr-container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="objective active">

      <div class="objective-header">
      <span class="objective-title">Building a Foundation</span>
      <span class="objective-options">...</span>
      </div>
      <div class="objective-details">
        <span class="objectives-count">4 objectives</span>
        <span class="objective-progress">8%</span>
      </div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="objective">
      <div class="objective-header">
      <span class="objective-title">Doing something</span>
      <span class="objective-options">...</span>
      </div>
      <div class="objective-details">
        <span class="objectives-count">4 objectives</span>
        <span class="objective-progress">90%</span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="column">

    <div class="objective">
      <div class="objective-header">
      <span class="objective-title">REEEEEEEEEE</span>
      <span class="objective-options">...</span>
      </div>
      <div class="objective-details">
        <span class="objectives-count">4 objectives</span>
        <span class="objective-progress">8%</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="objective active">
      <div class="objective-header">
      <span class="objective-title">Help me please</span>
      <span class="objective-options">...</span>
      </div>
      <div class="objective-details">
        <span class="objectives-count">4 objectives</span>
        <span class="objective-progress">90%</span>
      </div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="objective">
      <div class="objective-header">
      <span class="objective-title">REEEEEEEEEE</span>
      <span class="objective-options">...</span>
      </div>
      <div class="objective-details">
        <span class="objectives-count">4 objectives</span>
        <span class="objective-progress">8%</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="objective">
      <div class="objective-header">
      <span class="objective-title">Help me please</span>
      <span class="objective-options">...</span>
      </div>
      <div class="objective-details">
        <span class="objectives-count">4 objectives</span>
        <span class="objective-progress">90%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #F0F4F5
}
.okr-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.column {
  width: 328px;
}
.objective {
  width: 280px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0.5px solid #BFC5D0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 16px;
}

.circle {
  background: #FFF;
  border: 4px solid #09D2C7;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -13px;
  top: 35px;
}

.active {
  border: 2px solid #09D2C7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-left: 8px solid #09D2C7;
}

.objective-title {
  font-family: SF Pro Text;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.objective-options {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.objective-details {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 90%;
}

.objectives-count {
  font-family: SF Pro Text;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
}

.objective-progress {
  font-family: SF Pro Display;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 36px;
  /* identical to box height */

  float: right;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
}
```

[Here's what I have made so far on Codepen](https://codepen.io/johnrequiroso/pen/BaBJYmo). I was thinking of using SVG lines but I don't know much about them to proceed in a way where lines would link the right boxes together.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Thank you!

EDIT: This is not going to be a drag-and-drop thing. Just that when a user clicks a box, it just shows the child DIVs.

Comment: What is your output and expected output?

Comment: I would suggest to put a canvas and do these type of activities. It would be rather easier than struggling to connect dots in this way

Comment: If you are open to using jQuery, here's a jQuery plugin for you to try. 
[link](http://sebastien.drouyer.com/jquery.flowchart-demo)

Comment: @Sherzod There's an image at the top that explains what I was trying to get it to look like. The lines are a bit tricky to draw in just HTML and CSS. 

Comment: @joyBlanks I haven't really tried out using canvas in any way, would you be able to add html elements in there?

Comment: @ryanc Thanks for the reference! I'll see if it's something I can use.

Comment: i think the jquery flowchart is what you need, mentioned by ryanc. If you need canvas look at p5js or beizerjs

Comment: [Check out gojs](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/index.html), I linked you their examples. Also check "family Tree" or "DOM Tree" example, this looks like something you might want to use.